# How do I change the parameter between staging , production and localhost?

Tags: symfony

I am making symfony2 project.

There are staging,production,and localhost

I want to change the strings in codes such as 'gmail login password' per each servers.

How should I switch the parameter ?

use parameters.yml? config.yml?

or how symfony2 understand this server is production or staging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `paramerters.yml.dist` with sensible default values and all parameters needed. Every developer and on every staging/production server the `parameters.yml.dist` is copied to `parameters.yml` and the entries are changed to the actual needed values. The `parameters.yml` should never be checked in under version control.

As of symfony2.3 the handling of the `parameters.yml.dist` and `parameters.yml` (copying it, publish new parameters from dist) is done with every composer install/update.